# Windows Could Not Start Because the Following File Is Missing or Corrupt: \Winnt\System32\Config\Systemced

Tags: windows, windows-2000

On my Panasonic Cf 27 Touchbook running Windows 2000, boot fails with the following error message:

> Windows Could Not Start Because the Following File Is Missing or
>   Corrupt: \Winnt\System32\Config\Systemced

How can I restore it?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I think that *is* the exact error message. Everything else that comes up on that failure screen is just various things to try.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269075), there are several potential causes:

> This behavior can occur if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - A Promise Technology, Inc. ATA66 PCI controller card is installed in the computer. This issue typically occurs during the Windows 2000
>     installation process.  *(Which means that this is not likely the cause in your case.)*
> - The System hive in the registry is damaged or missing.
>
>   Windows 2000 may be unable to load the registry if it is too large. This issue can occur when a process writes too much data to the
>     System subkey in the registry. The System subkey is designed to
>     contain only the information that is necessary to boot the computer.
>
>   Computers that are based on Intel architecture or ARC (RISC) architecture can only use 16 megabytes (MB) of memory at this stage of
>     the boot process. The System registry subkey has to share the 16 MB
>     with the loader, kernel, HAL, and boot drivers. In some instances, the
>     size of the System subkey may be 13 MB or larger.

BTW, The letters "ced" at the end of the error message are not really part of the error message. The previous screen included these letters and was not completely erased when the error message appeared.

#### Resolution

I'll include only the portion relating to the second bullet, since the first potential cause isn't applicable in your case.

> **Restore a Backup of the System Hive**
>
> **IMPORTANT:** This procedure will not work on an active directory domain controller, because if you use the REPAIR folder system hive, then you are no longer a domain controller.
>
> Use the Repair Console tool to replace the backup copy of the System
>   hive from the repair folder. If the Repair Console tool is not
>   installed on your computer, you can run it from the Emergency Repair
>   process:
>
> 1. Use the Windows 2000 CD-ROM or the Windows 2000 Startup disk to start the computer.
> 2. When you see the "Welcome to Setup" message, press R for "repair."
> 3. Press C to run the Recovery Console tool.
> 4. Select the installation that you want to repair.
> 5. Type the administrator password.
>
> If the computer is a domain controller, type the password for Directory Services Restore Mode when you are prompted to do so.For
>   additional information about the Recovery Console tool, click the
>   article numbers below to view the articles in the Microsoft Knowledge
>   Base:
>
> [239803](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/239803) How to Change the Recovery Console Administrator Password on a Domain Controller
>       [223301](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/223301) Protection of the Administrator Account in the Offline SAM
>
> 6. At the Recovery Console command prompt, type the following commands, pressing ENTER after you type each command:
>
>    `cd system32\config`
>
>    `ren system system.old`
>
>    `ren system.alt systemalt.old`
> 7. If you have run the Emergency Repair Disk Wizard from Windows Backup and Recovery tools, copy the backup of the System hive from the
>      %SystemRoot%\Repair\Regback folder.
>
>    If you have not run the Emergency Repair Disk Wizard, copy the default System hive from the %SystemRoot%\Repair folder.
>
>    IMPORTANT: You need to restore the most recent copy of the System hive. You also need to reinstall any hardware device drivers or
>      programs that run as services that you installed since the last time
>      that you updated your Emergency Repair Disk.
>
>    To copy the default System hive, type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>
>    `copy c:\winnt\repair\system c:\winnt\system32\config`
>
>    To copy the System hive that was backed up the last time that you ran the Emergency Repair Disk Wizard, type the following command, and
>      then press ENTER:
>
>    `copy c:\winnt\repair\regback\system c:\winnt\system32\config`
> 8. At the command prompt, type exit, and then press ENTER to restart your computer.
>
> **Reduce the Size of the System Hive**
>
> If a large number of resources are shared on the computer, the registry may become too large. To resolve this issue, use the following steps.
>
> 1. Start registry editor (Regedt32.exe).
> 2. Locate and click the following key in the registry:
>      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Share`
> 3. On the Registry menu, click Save Key.
> 4. In the File name box, type Shares.new, and then click Save.
> 5. Locate and click the following key in the registry:
>      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
> 6. On the Registry menu, click Load Hive.
> 7. In the list of files, click the System.old file, and then click Open.
> 8. In the Key Name box type System.old, and then click OK.
> 9. Locate and click the following key in the registry:
>      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Select`
> 10. Note the setting for the Default value.
> 11. Locate and click the following key in the registry
>       `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System.old\ControlSetx\Services\LanmanServer\Shares`
>
>     where x is the number that you noted in step 8.
> 12. On the Registry menu, click Save Key.
> 13. In the File name box, type Shares.old, and then click Save.
> 14. Restore the Shares.new key to the System.old registry hive:
>       `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System.old\ControlSetx\Services\LanmanServer\Shares`
> 15. Click the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System.old key.
> 16. On the Registry menu, click Unload Hive.
> 17. Quit Registry Editor.
> 18. Restart the computer to the Recovery Console.
> 19. At the command prompt, type the following lines, pressing ENTER after you type each line:
>       `ren system system.org`
>
>     `ren system.old system`
> 20. At the command prompt, type exit, and then press ENTER to restart the computer.